# For several view, is it a good idea to use the Mediator ?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I have a project where i have a lot of views and i want to use the mediator pattern.
Is it a good idea ? also, do you have any ideas ?

Thx you :) Excuse me for my english.

Comment: This isn't very constructive at the moment. Try to explain more about your views, and how you see it working using this pattern. SO is about specific problems, not general design questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it could be a good idea if the following points are kept in mind while implementing.

1. The mediator class should work on the protocol of a view controller. Each view controller should confirm to that protocol.
2. The view controllers should share a common data source.
3. The updates in views should be passed to data source/data source controller. E.g. selected items.
4. The data source updates should be passed to active/selected view controller only.
5. When view controller is changed to some other view controller, then only the data source should be asked to provide new set of data before rendering the new view.

If the mediator class takes care of such things, this could be the best way to implement such a thing. Also you can achieve good extensibility using this pattern.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a lot of views you might want to use a mediator. The main reason to do this is if your classes refer to each other often/call methods in each other/share data. The mediator keeps classes from becoming too interdependent and gives you an easy way to define what information in what form is being passed around. Essentially you can know that the mediator will always return the information you want in the form you want, and not worry as much about a change in one class affecting another.

I find mediators to be kind of a pain, and you should only really do it if you have a TON of classes that need to be in constant communication AND you plan on keeping this program around for a while and editing/expanding/etc. If you're just presenting a view or two at a time and the views only need to talk to each other or communicate with other views very infrequently, it might be overkill.